# how to stop crashing android app while connected with network?

Tags: android

I  am working on android application, which mostly runs on internet. Now the problem is when I am using my app, due to internet the app is crashed. Thing is after turn on wife, I had written code to get the network status using connection manager class, it's giving  network is good and returning  a true value but actually  data through network is not processing(it means no internet access). so, how can i prevent app from crashes messages when network state is true and network access is false (NO Internet access).

Comment: did you try to add `try...catch` blocks?

Comment: turn on wife doesn't help..try turning on wifi...

Answer (score 2):

Try to check if device is connected or not before using internet from your app

```
    ConnectivityManager con=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    boolean wifi=con.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnectedOrConnecting();
    boolean internet=con.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnectedOrConnecting();
    //check Internet connection
    if(internet||wifi)
    {
        //your code
    }else{
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.title)
        .setTitle("No internet connection")
        .setMessage("Please turn on mobile data")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //code for exit
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);            
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        })
        .show();
    }
```

Don't forget to add required permissions

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: this checks whether mobile internet or wifi is turned on, but give no information about real connection... for example, wifi may be on, but provider disabled internet access

Comment: For that you need to create custom function

Comment: will you  guide to write the custom function?

Comment: thanks @Salauyou to understand the problem,  will you guide to write coustme function

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
 //Check if Internet Network is active
 private boolean checkNetwork() {
 boolean wifiDataAvailable = false;
 boolean mobileDataAvailable = false;
ConnectivityManager conManager = (ConnectivityManager)     
getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo[] networkInfo = conManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
for (NetworkInfo netInfo : networkInfo) {
 if (netInfo.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
  if (netInfo.isConnected())
     wifiDataAvailable = true;
       if (netInfo.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
       if (netInfo.isConnected())
         mobileDataAvailable = true;
}
   return wifiDataAvailable || mobileDataAvailable;
}
```

Do put your code in try catch blocks to see the exception.

Source : http://code2care.org/pages/how-to-check-internet-connection-wifi-3g-4g-is-active-on-android-programatically/

Comment: please tell the solution for   internet access not for network connection status

Answer (score 0):

Make one class `ConnectionDetector`

```
public class ConnectionDetector {

private Context _context;

public ConnectionDetector(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
}


public boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) {

        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {

                    return true;
                }

    }

    return false;
}
   }
```

Now in your Activity call it on onCreate() method as

```
 ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(this);

 if(cd.isConnectingToInternet) {

   // do your stuff here

 } else {
   // No Internet Connection
 }
```

Comment: my problem is not to detect the connection status. problem is  regarding network access. thank you for comment

Answer (score 0):

```
   //define global variable   

    public static boolean isHaveInternet = true;

    //add permission in androidmainfest file
    <receiver android:name="NetworkReciver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    //add class for networkcheck

    package com.example;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.util.Log;

     public class NetworkReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {

    boolean status = GeneralClass.getConnectivityStatusString(context);

    GeneralClass.isHaveInternet = status ? true : false;
    if (status)

        Log.e("NET-------------->", "connecte" + status);

    else
        Log.e("NET------------->", "not connecte" + status);
}
}

    //check network connection where  you want

    if (GeneralClass.isHaveInternet) 
    {
                    //your code

    } 
    else
    {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Internet connection not avilable",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: please tell the solution for   internet access not for network connection status. thanks for your reply